# java restful api call sql server stored procedure and get back json object

Tags: java, json, api, stored-procedures, restful-architecture

i'm writing a java web application that use restful api to call sql server stored procedure. i can manage primitive type like string or int or date but i'm not familiar how to get back a json object from a stored procedure call.
My stored procedure is very simple. i need to query a single table and get back the result in json format. i know this is possible with sql server 2016 but i'm using sql server 2014

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[readAllRegistryType]
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT IDTipoAnagrafica, TADescrizione FROM [dbo].[GAI_TIPO_ANAGRAFICA]

END
```

result is

```
=====================================================
|  IDTipoAnagrafica    | TADescrizione              |
=====================================================
|     1                | XXXXXXXX                   |
|     2                | YYYYYYYY                   |
|     3                | ZZZZZZZZ                   |
=====================================================
```

Comment: if there's a restful API in front of the stored procedure (as you describe), then the API can do the transformation of the object into JSON.

Comment: Hello ADyson, as i'm green bean do you have an example of trasformation?

Comment: not in java, sorry. haven't done java for about 15 years! I saw the question because it was tagged as SQL. I would guess google knows the answer somewhere though

Comment: Hi, i read that there are many json libraries for converting data into json object. is it the way i need to follow? please see an example here http://wilddiary.com/serialize-java-objects-json-back/

Comment: certainly I wouldn't advise you to write your own converter, there's no point when there are existing libraries. But I can't comment on which one you should use - like I said I don't use Java any more and have no knowledge of which is best. I would suggest you either ask another SO question tagged with Java or do your own research.